# Google spreadsheets How to get the output of CASE functionality in sql

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

Below I have given a dataset and expected output on google sheets. In a normal database, my query would have been Select industry, CASE WHEN change > 0 THEN count(ticker) END) as change, etc. How do I get the expected shown in the picture

[image]

I tried multiple Querys, arrayformula and several other functions, none of them has giving all the 3 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have an option. First it finds the unique values from industries, and then uses them in BYROW. Inside BYROW, it lists three values: `each` which is the name, the first `COUNTIFS` that finds the positive values, and the `COUNTIF` that counts all the occurences of the industry:

```
=LET(indus,TOCOL(UNIQUE(B2:B),1),
BYROW(indus,LAMBDA(each,
{each,COUNTIFS(C2:C,">0",B2:B,each),COUNTIF(B2:B,each)})))
```

[image]